# Improve precision on variables defined by integer quotient

Tags: fortran, precision

Say I have the following program:

```
program derp
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: ikind = selected_real_kind(18)
    real (kind = ikind) :: a = 2.0 / 3.0
    print*, a
end program derp
```

The program `derp` outputs `0.6666666865348815917`, which is clearly not 18 digits of precision. However, if I define `a=2.0` and `b=3.0` using the same method and *then* define `c=a/b` I get an output of `0.666666666666666666685`, which is good. How do I just define a variable as a quotient of integers and have it store all the digits of precision I want from `selected_real_kind`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try: `real (kind = ikind) :: a = 2.0_ikind / 3.0_ikind`

The reason is while the LHS is high precision, the RHS in your code example, 2.0 / 3.0, is not.   Fortran does that calculation in single precision and then assigns the result to the LHS.  The RHS side isn't calculated in higher precision because the LHS is high precision. `digits_kind` is the way of specifying the type of a constant `digits`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. It's kinda cheesy that you have to do that manually, but I can live with it.

Comment: It is a fundamental thing in Fortran, that RHS is evaluated without considering LHS and then assigned. There are more situations, where this is crucial.

Comment: evaluation RHS without regard for precision of the LHS is hardly unique to fortran.  If you do a=2/3 would you expect a float operation (maybe interger arithmetic is what you meant).  What is unique (maybe) to fortran is defaulting to single precision.  To bad there isn't a standard way to set the default.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant that it was cheesy that I have to do that for *every* variable defined by integer arithmetic (the program I'm working on has a few hundred.) It's pretty easy to do by finding instances of ".0" and replacing with ".0_ikind" though.