# Assigning a lower precision number to a higher precision in Fortran90

Tags: floating-point, fortran

A few questions regarding assigning literals in Fortran90.  Using gfortran 4.6.

program:

```
program scratch
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: RP = selected_real_kind(15)
  real(kind=RP) :: w,x,z
  real :: y

  w=2.2_RP
  x=2.2
  y=2.2
  z=2.125

  print*, w
  print*, x
  print*, y
  print '(F25.23)', y
  print*, z
end program scratch
```

output:

```
   2.2000000000000002     
   2.2000000476837158     
   2.20000005    
   2.20000004768371582031250
   2.1250000000000000
```

For each of the printouts I'd like to understand what the compiler/processor is doing.  E.g. `y` is displayed with 7 digits after the decimal point, but if we format the output, where are these other digits coming from?  They seem like they're the same ones that occur when a default-`real` literal `2.2` is assigned to a higher precision, `kind=RP` real `x`.  So are the literals being converted to base 2, then changing precision afterwards, or something like that?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473441/improve-precision-on-variables-defined-by-integer-quotient/

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23736413/2068635

Comment: Note in this example the "extra" `2031250` are not random digits.  This is the value you get by taking the single precision binary representation and padding it with zeros to higher precision in binary. ( It is exactly `9227469/4194304` )

Comment: The closest 32 bit IEEE 754 binary floating point to 2.2 is 2.2000000476837158203125. The closest 64 bit is 2.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the assignment to y. It is a single-precision variable and you assign a single-precision value to it. The decimal value is converted to the floating point representation used, which on most platforms is IEEE single precision, a binary floating point type. This has 23 bits of fraction, 8 bits of exponent and a sign bit. Because 2.2 isn't exactly representable in binary floating point, you get the closest (hopefully) representable value.

Those "other digits" when you print to more places are the single precision value converted to decimal - since it isn't exact in decimal it tends to have additional non-zero digits. Some implementations will give you a reasonable number of additional digits, some might start to give you zeroes after a while, and some might just give random digits.

2.125 is exactly representable in binary floating point, so it can be exactly converted in both directions.